# How to Attach debbuger to process from the first line without compile code every time

Tags: android

I'm trying save compiling time only for debug first app lines code.

There is solution to exit by *backPress()* and the process still running (and then i can attach debugger to process), but my debug scenario need to check app from start so i need to kill process before debug, which prevent me to attach debugger unless otherwise i'm compiling the app in debug mode.

Does any one know how to prevent compile in debug only for that?

Answer (score 0):

go to settings -> Developer options -> Select app to be debugged -> choose your app

turn on 'Wait for debugger'

then when you launch the app you see this screen:

[image]

Now app wait for you to attach debugger and auto start when it's attached

It is actually start the app-process without start launcher activity